# How to combine Identity.Application and JWT authentication using IdentityServer4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, jwt, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

How to configure IdentityServer4 and authentication to use both Identity.Application (for IdentityServer4 endpoints) and JWT (for API requests)?

Trying to implement ASP.NET 6 application, that combines authorization server and resource server functionality. Configured authorization code flow with PKCE for Angular SPA, that is hosted separately. Added Identity Razor pages.

Experimented with couple of code examples. Works only this one:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        // Authorization server base URL
        // We can't get the base URL during services configuration, so it is hardcoded
        options.Authority = _webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment() ? "https://localhost:5000" : "https://threadbox.prod";
        // API resource
        options.Audience = "threadbox_api";
    });
```

but only if I set `AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;` for `AuthorizeAttribute`. This allows to read identity only in authorization handlers (PermissionHandler.cs) - authentication type is 'AuthenticationTypes.Federation'. Middleware can identify only identity with authentication type 'Identity.Application' (PermissionsMiddleware.cs).

Repos:
https://github.com/vladbarkovsky/threadbox.api - branch vlad-barkovsky/identity-razor
https://github.com/vladbarkovsky/threadbox.front - branch main

Startup:

```
        services
            .AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
            {
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
            })
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        var identityServerBuilder = services.AddIdentityServer();

        if (_webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            identityServerBuilder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
        }
        else
        {
            // Use SSL certificate
        }

        identityServerBuilder
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureDbContext = builder =>
                {
                    builder.UseNpgsql(
                        _configuration.GetConnectionString(AppSettings.ConnectionStrings.Development),
                        // TODO: Assembly name should not be hardcoded
                        options => options.MigrationsAssembly("ThreadboxApi"));
                };

                options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
            })
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(new List<IdentityResource>
            {
                new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                new IdentityResources.Profile()
            })
            .AddInMemoryApiScopes(new List<ApiScope>
            {
                new ApiScope("threadbox_api.access", "Threadbox API"),
            })
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(new List<ApiResource>
            {
                new ApiResource
                {
                    Name = "threadbox_api",
                    Scopes = { "threadbox_api.access" }
                }
            })
            .AddInMemoryClients(new List<Client>
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "angular_client",
                    ClientName = "Threadbox",

                    AllowedCorsOrigins =
                    {
                        _configuration[AppSettings.ClientBaseUrl]
                    },

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                    RequirePkce = true,
                    RequireClientSecret = false,
                    AllowOfflineAccess = true,

                    AllowedScopes =
                    {
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                        "threadbox_api.access"
                    },

                    RedirectUris =
                    {
                        _configuration[AppSettings.ClientBaseUrl] + "/authorization/sign-in-redirect-callback",
                        _configuration[AppSettings.ClientBaseUrl] + "/authorization/sign-in-silent-callback"
                    },

                    PostLogoutRedirectUris =
                    {
                        _configuration[AppSettings.ClientBaseUrl] + "/authorization/sign-out-redirect-callback"
                    },
                },
            });

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                // Authorization server base URL
                // We can't get the base URL during services configuration, so it is hardcoded
                options.Authority = _webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment() ? "https://localhost:5000" : "https://threadbox.prod";
                // API resource
                options.Audience = "threadbox_api";
            });

        services.AddAuthorization();

        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, PermissionHandler>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationPolicyProvider, PermissionPolicyProvider>();

        services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        services.AddMediatR(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        });

        services.AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();

        services.AddMvc();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            // Disable redirecting for unauthorized HTTP requests
            options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };

            // Disable redirecting for forbidden HTTP requests
            options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied = context =>
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            };
        });

        app.UseExceptionHandler();

        // Enable HTTP routing
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMiddleware<PermissionsMiddleware>();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();
```

PermissionsMiddleware:

```
public class PermissionsMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public PermissionsMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IdentityService identityService)
    {
        if (context.Request.Path == "/api/Boards/GetBoardsList")
        {
            var x = context.User.Identity.AuthenticationType;
        }

        if (context.User.Identity.AuthenticationType == "Identity.Application" || context.User.Identity.AuthenticationType == null)
        {
            await _next(context);
            return;
        }

        var userId = context.User.FindFirst("sub")?.Value;

        //if (userId == null)
        //{
        //    await _next(context);
        //    return;
        //}

        var permissionsIdentity = await identityService.GetUserPermissionsIdentity(userId);

        if (permissionsIdentity != null)
        {
            context.User.AddIdentity(permissionsIdentity);
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}
```

PermissionHandler:

```
public class PermissionHandler : AuthorizationHandler<PermissionRequirement>
{
    public PermissionHandler()
    { }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, PermissionRequirement requirement)
    {
        var hasPermission = context.User.HasClaim(PermissionContants.ClaimType, requirement.Permission);

        if (!hasPermission)
        {
            context.Fail();
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also trying to configure IdentityServer4 using ApiAuthorization.
https://github.com/vladbarkovsky/threadbox.api/tree/vlad-barkovsky/idsrv-etop

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem by using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApiAuthorization.IdentityServer

```
var identityServerBuilder = services
    .AddIdentityServer()
    .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
    .AddApiResources()
    .AddIdentityResources()
    .AddClients()
    .AddOperationalStore<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    {
        options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
    })
    .AddClientStore<InMemoryClientStore>()
    .AddResourceStore<InMemoryResourcesStore>();

if (_webHostEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
{
    identityServerBuilder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
}
else
{
    // Use SSL certificate
}

services.Configure<ApiAuthorizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Clients.AddSPA("angular_client", builder =>
    {
        builder
            .WithRedirectUri(_configuration[AppSettings.ClientBaseUrl] + "/authorization/sign-in-redirect-callback")
            .WithRedirectUri(_configuration[AppSettings.ClientBaseUrl] + "/authorization/sign-in-silent-callback")
            .WithLogoutRedirectUri(_configuration[AppSettings.ClientBaseUrl] + "/authorization/sign-out-redirect-callback");
    });
});

// TODO: Check if required
JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

```
  private userManager = new UserManager({
    authority: environment.apiBaseUrl,
    client_id: 'angular_client',
    scope: 'openid profile ThreadboxApiAPI',
    response_type: 'code',
    redirect_uri: this.document.baseURI + 'authorization/sign-in-redirect-callback',
    silent_redirect_uri: this.document.baseURI + 'authorization/sign-in-silent-callback',
    post_logout_redirect_uri: this.document.baseURI + 'authorization/sign-out-redirect-callback',
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
  });
```

But this solution is not ideal, since, for example, it does not allow to configure offline access. Ideally, would be to find what configuration creates `.AddSPA(...)` and `.AddIdentityServerJwt()` in order to copy it.